# How to change Alert time of SharePoint Search Result Alerts in SharePoint Online/Office 365?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search

By Default, SharePoint online/Office 365 provides two options for receiving Search Result Alerts. One is Daily Summary and another is Weekly Summary. I have requirement to update the frequency and want to schedule Search Alerts at a specific time.

Is there any possible way to achieve this? Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SharePoint Online, there is no alternate option if you want to change the alert time of search result. Please see below reference url which will help you to get familiar with Search Result alert and how it works.

- http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.in/2015/06/sharepoint-2013-search-weirdness-part-3.html
- http://www.chrisdomino.com/blog/post/The-Truth-About-How-Daily-SharePoint-Alerts-Actually-Work

Hope this will help you.